# Telerik Report, Unable to perform print operation

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, telerik

I am having a problem with Telerik Reports Printing.I am using Telerik Reports with Telerik Report Viewer. In Chrome when i click Print button it 
gives me an alert

'Unable to Perform the Print Operation'

I googled on it and found from Telerik forums that Adobe plugin should be installed and enabled 
in order to use Print, I updated my Adobe Plugin in Chrome,

This solution has resolved problem only on my local server but on Live server(www.xyz.com)
it is still giving me the same alert. I am using GoDaddy hosting server.

What should i do in order to perform the Print operation of Telerik Reporting on Live Server using Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a client related issue, not a server one. If the user trying to perform the print operation is using chrome, then he will have to install the pluggin aswell, no matter what is setup on the server.

Installing it on the server would do nothing for the other clients.

One possible solution for you would be to generate the PDF file from the report and send it directly to the client, without using the report viewer (there's a report processor object, it is well documented on their websites). And if you still want to provide the preview, try adding to buttons: "preview" and "print".

Comment: But my on my local host it is working fine. this issue is just on live server

Comment: Yes because this is not related to the server. It is client using the report processor (the web browser) that has the issue. If it works on your local host, it is simply because the web browser you are using has the extension required. This is a well known Chrome limitation, try the solution I described (process the report as PDF and send it directly to the client instead going through the report viewer). It is the only "safe" workaround I know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this Problem
Just put this code in web.config and problem will be resolved

```
<system.web>
<trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```